# navigation subform requery stopped working

Tags: sql, forms, ms-access

I've built an unbound form which allows a user to select from two combo boxes that contain related information (Zone and Watershed Unit -- each Zone contains multiple watershed units) in order to see what regulations apply to each.  Based on these selections (stored in `txtZone` and `txtWU` on the main form) a subform would show the existing regulations (sfrmRegsbyZWU based on qryRegsbyZWU).  This serves as a reference for the user, who picks a new regulation to add from another subform, clicks a button, and the selection is added to the regulations for the Zone/Watershed Unit selected.  I had this successfully built with a workaround in the `OnCurrent` event of the subform (which was undesirable because the user couldn't click on a record and delete it) and everything worked until I added inserted code to change the query definitions for the query which is the basis for the subform as opposed to having it in the "`On current`" event of the subform.

At that point the requery syntax in the main form which had previously worked stopped working.  This is in all embedded in a navigation form in Access 2010, so the previously working syntax was:

`Forms!frmNav!NavigationSubform.Form.sfrmRegsbyZWU.Requery`

I've tried every permutation of Requery I can think of, and I can not get it working. The underlying query has been changed, but the form doesn't update to reflect it. Can anyone explain to me what has gone wrong, and how to fix it?  The code (attached to the `_After Update()` event of the combo boxes) is:

```
    Private Sub cboZone_AfterUpdate()
    'Changes WU combo box as well as the underlying text boxes

    Me.cboWU.SetFocus
    Me.cboWU = ""

    'Blank out other selections

    Me.txtWU.SetFocus
    Me.txtWU = ""

    'Update text box with combobox selection
    Me.txtZone.SetFocus
    Me.txtZone = Me!cboZone.Column(0)

   'Change the query underlying the Existing Regs panel (frmRegsbyZWU, qryRegsbyZWU) to reflect selection

    Dim strZSQL As String

    Set qdfZ = CurrentDb().QueryDefs("qryRegsbyZWU")

    Dim myZVar As Variant

        myZVar = Forms!frmNav!NavigationSubform.Form.txtZone

        'MsgBox (myZVar)

    If IsNull(myZVar) Then

         strZSQL = "SELECT * FROM tblRegulations WHERE FALSE"

    Else

        strZSQL = "SELECT * FROM tblRegulations WHERE Zone_No=" & Forms!frmNav!NavigationSubform.Form.txtZone


    End If

        'MsgBox (strZSQL)

    qdfZ.SQL = strZSQL

    'DoCmd.OpenQuery ("qryRegsbyZWU")

  Forms!frmNav!NavigationSubform.Form.sfrmRegsbyZWU.Requery
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Have you tried putting Forms!frmNav!NavigationSubform.Form.sfrmRegsbyZWU.Refresh underneath the requery?

Comment: `Forms("frmNav").NavigationSubform.Form.sfrmRegsbyZWU.Form.Requery` maybe?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but neither worked.  Using Refresh after Requery netted me a run-time error (#438 "Object Doesn't Support This Property or Method").  Using Forms ("frmNav") didn't produce any errors, but didn't refresh the form either.  I am completely stumped, and more than a little frustrated. Frankly this makes me not want to use the Navigation Form feature in future designs because it's so impenetrable.

Comment: As an update, I still haven't found a solution to this problem.  If I move the sql code for the query to a box on the "main" form and set the subform (frmRegsbyZWU) _OnCurrent event to reference the code as a .Recordsource it updates and shows what I've selected.  However, because it's in _OnCurrent you can't do anything with the data in the subform, which is not ideal.  So the answer for now is that Forms!frmNav!NavigationSubform.Form.sfrmRegsbyZWU.Requery *does* work, but strangely.  Hopefully this can help someone else out who is also lost!

Comment: SOLVED! I ended up solving this myself, but it was convoluted. The issue was that refreshing the subform wasn't working from the main form (presumably because they're both embedded in the navigation form). Either events were unsupported, or they weren't being triggered. The solution was to move the refresh sequence to a module which would be called from a user changing the main form. In the module I reset the Source Object for the form: [code]Forms!frmNav!NavigationSubform.Form.sfrmRegsbyZWU.SourceObject = "Query.qryRegsbyZWU"[/code] followed by [code]Forms!frmNav(etc.).Refresh[/code].